# copying file with shutil.copy2 in python creates file of zero Kbs

Tags: python, file-copying, shutil

hi i am trying to copy a file using shutil.copy2  but it creates a file of zero Kb at the destination..i am using mac os 10.6.7 .The problem is not with all files but some specific files only .The problem is independent of the extension of file

Comment: Works fine for me. Must be something special about your files or your system.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  : it works for some files ..but for few specific files it fails. i want to know if it is a known issue

Comment: More details please: 1) Which files do not work 2) code snippet 3) ...

Comment: What is special about the files it fails?

Comment: @Nicoretti : As i said ,it is extension independent.. i have a font file in my system which i want to copy through script ..don't think adding code would be of much help since the same code works for other files.im simply using shutil.copy2 function

Comment: Can you copy the file using the ``cp`` shell command?

Comment: @codeape : yeah it works fine with cp shell command

Comment: From the copy2 documentation: "This is similar to the Unix command cp -p". Try ``cp -p`` in the shell. Does that work as well?

Comment: Also, could you paste the following: 1. The ``cp`` command that works 2. The corresponding python statement that doesn't work.

Comment: @codeape :cp -p works fine ..

Comment: Who creates the file you're trying to copy? Is it created from the same process? If so, remember to close (or at least flush) it before attempting to copy it.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you have proper read access to the source file as the user running the Python program. Unfortunately it seems `copy()` and `copy2()` don't return any error information.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and found your question and one other. I posted an "answer" on that one that might be helpful to anyone that finds your question, like I did.

[Files are copied but size remains 0 KB using shutil.copy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731390/files-are-copied-but-size-remains-0-kb-using-shutil-copy2/39879794#39879794)