# Files are copied but size remains 0 KB using shutil.copy2

Tags: python, file-copying

I am able to copy files from different directories but the file contents are not copied. I am not sure what mistake I am doing:

```
import os,zipfile,shutil
rootdir = r'Y:\StorageReports\Mitrend_Reports\test'
adddir=r'Y:\StorageReports\Mitrend_Reports\test\additional'
sheetdir=r'Y:\StorageReports\Mitrend_Reports\test\spreadsheets'
extn="pptx"
extn1="xlsx"

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for i in files:
        if "Validate the Value" or "VNX Additional Details" in i:
        if i.endswith (extn):    
                f=os.path.join(dirpath,i)
                print (f)
                shutil.copy2(f,adddir)
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for j in files:
        #if "Validate the Value" or "VNX Additional Details" in j:
        if j.endswith (extn1):    
            f1=os.path.join(dirpath,j)
            print (f1)
            shutil.copy2(f1,sheetdir)
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for k in files:
        #print (k)
        if "VNX Profile" in k:
            print(k)
            f2=os.path.join(dirpath,k)
            print(f2)
            shutil.copy2(f2,rootdir)

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for l in files:
        #print (k)
        if "Workload Overview" in l:
            print(l)
            f3=os.path.join(dirpath,l)
            print(f3)
            shutil.copy2(f3,rootdir)
```

What is the mistake I am making?

Comment: Format your code, so that we can help you

Comment: Do the directories of dirpaths exist within rootdir, sheetdir, and adddir?

Comment: Could you print or watch in debugger value of `f` variable before you use `shutil.copy2`?

Comment: @Alexander - All these directories exists. When I execute the copy command, all the files are copied and it displays them. But the size of the files is 0 KB.

Comment: I am not sure how to watch it in debug mode. But when I print the value of f, I can see all the files that I need to see displayed. As i said earlier all the files are copied to the destination correctly, but the file data is not copied.

Comment: This is probably not the root issue, but your line if "Validate the Value" or "VNX Additional Details" in i: looks wrong... as far as i can tell, this gets interpretted as if True or ("VNC Additional Details" in i): which is always True... I think you want if "Validate the Value" in i or "VNX Additional Details" in i:

Comment: Thanks. I will try to change the code and try

Answer (score 0):

This only happens when shutil.copy(), copy2(), copyfile() does NOT have "clean" access to the file. in most cases this is because you have not closed the file before trying to copy it. Not having read permissions on the first file could cause this too.

I just had this problem because I had the same program scheduled twice at the same time. Stepping all over each other.